# GIMP does not unload closed image from memory

Tags: gimp

[GIMP exported an image that was closed and not show in GIMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuRTN.jpg)

I need a little bit of help!

I have found that GIMP does not always remove closed images from its working memory even if they are not shown.

As you can see here, I have 4 open images, but when I export all of them I actually get 5 JPGs.  The extra one was from some earlier image I played with, exported, and saved the XCF just in case I needed it.

It is not my code Since that is more or less directly out of the playbook (see below).  Now this is an issue with GIMP, and it explains why I have seen GIMP hugging memory like creasy.  You may never see this issue since many people open GIMP work on one to a handful of images and then closes the program.  I on the other hand can have GIMP open for weeks so it is ready to run when I need something.  I do the same with Word and other programs like the Browser.

Any input is appreciated.....

```
        image_list = gimp.image_list()
        image_ptr = len(image_list)
        for image in image_list:
            fullfilepath = os.path.join(output_folder, filename)
            fullfilepath = clean_string(fullfilepath)
            if (overwrite_index == 1):
                fullfilepath = get_clean_filename(fullfilepath)
            if (fullfilepath != ""):
                raw_filename = filename.encode('utf-8')
                pdb.gimp_file_save(image, image.active_layer, fullfilepath, raw_filename)
                pdb.gimp_image_clean_all(image)
```

Debugged my code and it is solid - I think this is a old bug in GIMP

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. You have not asked any question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Images` dockable dialog (`Windows > Dockable dialogs > Images`) to check all images loaded in Gimp, even those without an attached display. These display-less image can be deleted ([image] icon at the bottom of the dialog, or right-click).

I cannot see any bug about this in the Gimp issues list. But lingering images can be a different problem, for instance a script that creates duplicates and doesn't delete them (code oversight, or crash before being able to delete the image).